# Is node js mysql multithread faster than syncronous requests

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

If we use php, we do synchronous mysql calls. We run one mysql query per time, then wait for result, then run another and so on.
If we do it in node.js, we do it async, so we run ten requests at a time.

So would node.js be ten times faster than php in such situation, if we run ten queries at a time?

Comment: why dont you test it and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really

Every server can only share as many resources as it has.

If you run only 1 query it will use all resources needed to finish it.

If you have 3 threads, you have to share those resources and you can have locks that can even further delay queries.

besides you can try multi-queries, to increase speed, if it fits into your workflow

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your choice of database abstraction layer in PHP. There are several database abstraction layers that you can use in PHP to make queries to database. Examples: PDO, mysqli etc. Most of them are synchronous, however, there are also asynchronous. For example mysqli allows to make asynchronous calls to database. If you use such asynchronous drivers in PHP then they also can run ten requests at a time. However, if you use native drivers such as PDO, then nodejs will be faster.
There is an example of async query in PHP with mysqli extenstion: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.reap-async-query.php